# how can i code and then decode quantized channels using huffman coding?

Tags: matlab

I have to implement a compression scheme.i have quantized the image 's 3 channels using the following commands:

```
yce = blockproc(y, [8 8], @(block_struct) round(round(block_struct.data) ./ q_y));
cbce = blockproc(cb, [8 8], @(block_struct) round(round(block_struct.data) ./ q_c));
crce = blockproc(cr, [8 8], @(block_struct) round(round(block_struct.data) ./ q_c));
```

now i want to code each element above using huffman coding,and then perform the inverse operation.this is my code:

```
Z = unique (yce); 

countElY=histc(yce,Z);

p = countElY/numel(yce);

[dict,avglen] = huffmandict(Z,p);

K=unique(cbce);

countelcb=histc(cbce,K);

p1=countelcb/numel(cbce);

[dict1,avglen1]=huffmandict(K,p1);

L=unique(crce);

countelcr=histc(crce,L);

p2=countelcr/numel(crce);

[dict2,avglen2]=huffmandict(L,p2);

comp= huffmanenco(yce,dict);

comp1=huffmanenco(cbce,dict1);

comp2=huffmanenco(crce,dict2);

huffman_code = (cat(3,comp,comp1,comp2));

Im1 = huffmandeco(comp,dict);

im2=huffmandeco(comp1,dict1);

im3=huffmandeco(comp2,dict2);
```

I get the following error:

```
The probability input must be a vector.
```

Can you please help me in this step?thanks in advance

Comment: Could you edit your post to format it a bit better?  You have your own sentences showing up inside a code block and it's very difficult to read for people who might be able to help.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, I don't know the first thing about matlab.  I was just trying to advise you make your question easier to read and understand to improve the chances of getting it answered.  The more detail you can provide the better: when do you see the error?  Does the message provide a line number? maybe provide your full (formatted) code? etc. etc.